# Ionic Video Mute Attribute Ignored

Tags: angular, html, ionic-framework

I am having a weird issue where the mute tag on a video element is being ignored.

```
   <video #media playsinline webkit-playsinline loop muted
   [src]="video_url"
   class="videoPlayer"
   preload="metadata"
   type="video/mp4">
   </video>
```

The muted or muted="true" is being overlooked and the video continues to be played with sound.

I understand that you can mute videos through java-script and while that works, iOS will not allow the video to be auto played until the video is clicked first.

Is there any reason I would be seeing this behavior with the HTML part of the video?

Thanks,

Troy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I can see you have

> #media

Do you want this to be `id="media"`?

The other thing I can see is that your

> muted="true"

is invalid syntax for declaring a Boolean attribute. Just add `muted="muted"`.

Also, when you say

> you can mute videos through java-script and while that works, iOS will not allow the video to be auto played until the video is clicked first.

Do you mean that you want the video to be autoplayed when you load the page? In that case, add `autoplay="autoplay"`.

Comment: `<video> elements will be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture if their source media contains no audio tracks.
<video muted> elements will also be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture.
If a <video> element gains an audio track or becomes un-muted without a user gesture, playback will pause.`



A video that is not muted will not play automatically unless by user gesture. In my app, I auto-play videos when they are in view. I just tried muted="muted" and that did not seem to fix anything either. My problem occurs in the browser as well as on a device.

Comment: Played around with it more because I am using videogular2 as well and it appears muted="muted" is now working correctly. Thank you so much, I don't know how I never came across that.

Comment: No worries, always glad to help! P.S. are you going to award the bounty?

Comment: Yea, I have to wait 24 hours after I set the bounty so I will do it tomorrow

Comment: Thanks so much. That was an excellent question BTW so I'll vote it tomorrow as well.